# Python CGI getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I'm making first python script. I've uploaded the script in `public_html/cgi-bin` folder with `777` permission.

I'm getting this 500 Internal server error. I've wrote the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
print "<html><head><title>CGI</title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "hello cgi"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Comment: What error are you seeing in the server's log?

Comment: Can you post the output of `/usr/bin/python --version` ? If you're in version 3, you have to put parenthesis for the print statement

Comment: @FunkySayu I'm on shared hosting. How to get output of `/usr/bin/python --version` on shared hosting ? via cPanel ?

Comment: Still not working. I've tried parenthesis for print statement. I doubt that  `#!/usr/bin/python` is wrong. How can i check the path for python ? with `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: I don't know of any hosting providers that use Arch Linux or any other system that puts Python 3 at  `/usr/bin/python`, so that's not likely to be the problem… but it never hurts to rule it out.

Comment: Neither of these is your problem, but: (1) HTTP requires `\r\n` line endings, not `\n`. Many browsers will handle `\n` just because so many people make this mistake, but it's better to do it right. (2) Each `print` already includes a newline, unless you end it with a comma, so you're adding two blank lines between the headers and body, not one blank line.

Comment: I said "neither of these is your problem". The `\n` is not causing this error--but it is still wrong, so you need to fix that _too_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every thing was fine except `cgi-bin` directory's permission.

Change the permission (chmod) of **cgi-bin** to **755** from 777.

Comment: I am curious about why it isn't working with 777 permission ?

Comment: @SohanPatel: For security reasons, some programs can be configured to refuse to execute anything that's world-writable, and/or in a world-writable directory. That prevents someone from modifying or replacing your CGI script to make it email your users' passwords to North Korea and then tricking your users into running it. Presumably your Apache is configured that way.